# WPF: Is there a way to directly get the Window object a control is on?

Tags: wpf, window, controls

Is there a way to directly get the Window object a control is on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the Control is directly below the Window, you can call [GetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.logicaltreehelper.getparent.aspx) on the  LogicalTreeHelper.

You may, of course, need to Use the `LogicalTreeHelper` to traverse the tree if the Control is not a direct descendant.

Comment: That's better than what I currently have, but I'm a bit annoyed that there isn't a GetWindow method.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are on the applications active window in the moment you interact with the control.

So in that case, this other post on stackoverflow could be helpful too:

[stackoverflow: get active window(s) in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038879/refer-to-active-window-in-wpf)

Comment: That looks like it would be very fragile for my use case, but I;ll give you a point because it would be really useful when displaying a pop-up window with CenterOwner set.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but the following works pretty fine for me.

```
var ownerWindow = Window.GetWindow(yourControl);
```